# Setting value of async function to the value of the return of the .then

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

edit: maybe I have simplified my example too much. Let me try again

```
file1.js
import conditonFunction from './conditonFunction'
console.log(conditonFunction()) 


file2.js
import asyncFunction from './asyncFunction'


export const conditonFunction = () => {
  if (condition) {
 return 'this doesnt matter'
  } else {
    asyncFunction().then(res => {
      return res[0].whatever
    })
  }
}
```

if my condition is not met, I want the logged value of `conditonFunction` to be the value of `res` inside of `asyncFunction`

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you really calling `asyncFunction()` twice? Please also fix the syntax error - the `then(` call is missing a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is using [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) functions.

```js
function asyncFunction() {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(7);
      }, 2000);
   });
}

async function main() {
  var res = await asyncFunction(); 
  console.log(res);
}

main();
```

```html
Wait for 2 seconds...
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for

```
asyncFunction().then(res => {
    return res[0].whatever;
}).then(console.log);
```

or simply

```
asyncFunction().then(res => {
    console.log(res[0].whatever);
});
```